# How to get data from website

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, foundation

I need to have a variable that contains the text of a label. But the label is in a website in aspx.
I try with NSURLSession but i don't understand which method is correct.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is simple way

1) Get the html content from the url: you can use 
  - NSURLSession
         NSURLSession *session =
    [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig
                                  delegate:nil
                             delegateQueue:nil];

```
[[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]
        completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                            NSURLResponse *response,
                            NSError *error) {
```

- NSURLConnection:

```
NSURLConnection *urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:self.request delegate:self];
```

- dataWithContentsOfURL:

  NSData * htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

2) Parse the variable content from that content using TFHpple

```
TFHpple *xpathParser = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:htmlData];
NSArray *elements  = [xpathParser search:@"//variable"]; // get the variable
```

Hope it help

Comment: It is correct. you can google to see the swift version